# Powershell. How to check that no string in array starts with some character?

Tags: powershell, iteration

I already know how to check if a string in an array DOES start with some character:

```
foreach ($str in $arr) {
    if ($str.StartsWith("abc")) {
        do this
    }
}
```

But I need the code that will have somewhat different logic:
"if no string in this array starts with abc, then do this"

Please help me to build code for that with the means of Powershell. I have no clue.

Answer (score 4):

Using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration) and this [comparison operator feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features):

> When the input of an operator is a scalar value, the operator returns a **Boolean** value. When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison operators return an empty array. For example:

```
if (!($Arr.StartsWith("abc") -eq $True)) {
    'no string in $arr starts with abc'
}
```

If it concerns a very large array and you don't want to search further when any string starting with `abc` is already found (as the helpful suggestion from **[Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)**), you might also use the PowerShell [`Where` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where):

```
if (!($Arr.Where({ $_.StartsWith("abc") }, 'First'))) {
    'no string in $arr starts with abc'
}
```

**Note** that in comparison with PowerShell's native case sensitivity the [.Net `StartsWith` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith) *is* case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

The `-like` comparison operator will act as a filter when you apply it to an array - making it easy to determine if *any string* in the array starts with `abc`:

```
if(@($arr) -like 'abc*'){
    # at least 1 string in $arr starts with abc
}
```

To get the opposite, use the `-not` operator:

```
if(-not(@($arr) -like 'abc*')){
    # no string in $arr starts with abc
}
```

Comment: What does `@($arr)` do if `$arr` is already an array?  Is that needed if $arr contains only one element?  Also, the logic seems flipped.  I think he wants something similar to `if(-not ($arr -like 'abc*')){<#Do something#>}`.

Comment: @Darin `@($arr)` ensures a scalar (eg. a single non-collection) value gets wrapped in an array. It may be inefficient if `$arr` is very very large

Comment: While certainly elegant, using the operators as filters is inefficient for large arrays, as all array elements are processed and a new array containing all matches is constructed. Actually it would be sufficient to break when the 1st matching array element is found.

Comment: @zett42, doing some test on Mathias, iRon and Santiago's code.  Mathias' code consistently takes around 0.469 seconds in the test I'm doing while iRon's code is consistently around 1.565 seconds and Santiago's code varies from 0.159 to 1.361 seconds.  This is in Win10 and PS 5.1.  Haven't tried it in PS Core, but I expect better results there.

Comment: @Darin What test? Performance characteristics will depend entirely on the size of `$arr` and whether any matches occur (or not) if you take "time to first result" into account like zett42 suggests

Comment: For anybody who cares, I benchmarked this answer against using `if(-NOT $arr.Contains("abc")){write-host test}` instead, and I found that using `-like` for this is a little over twice as fast.

Comment: @shadow2020 with what input? [`.Where({...},'First')` is much faster _when a match occurs early in a large array_ but terribly slow compared to the other approaches when there's no match](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/e6b104ad8e5ea599ca2445bb05a2afc7)

Comment: That is a good point. I just evaluated an array with 3 or 4 items using Measure-Object. What you say makes perfect sense though. Perhaps I didn't have the right sample size of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the code you already have and showing a different alternative, you can loop through each element of the array and when the condition becomes true you can return `$true` and [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.2) your loop as no further comparison is needed:

```
$comparison = foreach ($str in $arr) {
    if ($str.StartsWith("abc")) {
        $true
        break
    }
}

if(-not $comparison) {
    # here is if no element of `$arr` starts with abc
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using your example:

```
foreach ($str in $arr) {
    if (-not $str.StartsWith("abc")) {
        do this
    }
}
```

Or,

```
$Filter = @('abc', 'def', 'abcghj') | Where-Object { -not $_.startswith('a') }
```

Then you can iterate over `$Filter`

Edit: I understood OPs question wrong,

```
# This var is empty if all elements do not match
$MatchFound = @('abc', 'def', 'abcghj') | Where-Object { $_.StartsWith('efg') }

if (-not $MatchFound)
{
    # Do something
}
```

From your code:

```
# If match found $MatchFound will be set to True
$MatchFound = foreach ($str in $arr) {
    if ($str.StartsWith("abc")) {
       $True 
       break
    }
}

# Only do something when no matches were found, i.e. $MatchFound was empty
if (-not $MatchFound)
{
    # Do something
}
```

Comment: I believe the logic is inaccurate, OP wants to do something if __all elements__ not match a condition, this would do something __for any element__ not matching a condition

Comment: Yes, thanks for an accurate description, @Santiago Squarzon.

Comment: Okay, I've added an edit, let me know your thoughts!